# How to use :make without opening a blank file afterwards?

Tags: visual-c++, vim, compilation, msbuild

I'm developing a C++ application and every time I call `:make my_project.vcxproj` with `:compiler msvc` and `:set makeprg=msbuild`, and `:set shellpipe=>%s 2>&1`,  vim opens a blank file called `Build Started 26\03\2014`.

I've tried playing around with the `shellpipe` option: setting it to blank, `:set shellpipe=`results in vim opening the msbuild in a new window and displaying the results there, and sending nothing to the quickfix. Setting `:set shellpipe=>` opens a blank file similarly named, but missing part of the date.

How can I have vim avoid opening a new buffer for the output of my make command?

Comment: It is not clear for me what exactly is this blank file. You said that the result is going to quickfix, so this blank file is something like the first entry on the quickfix? If it is you could avoid it by using `:make!` instead of `:make`.

Comment: @mMontu that's part of my issue. I'm not sure what's causing it. The file is simply named 'Build Started' and the date, but there is no content inside at all. The quickfix is populated as expected. `:make!` solved my issue so it was a line in my quickfix, I didn't realize. Throw that up as an answer and I'll accept it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the result is going to the quickfix, it is probably that one of the first lines is the message about the build starting.

Vim is probably interpreting that line as an error/warning message containing the file name and line number, and is trying to jump to it.

The `:make` command calls the `makeprg` and then jump to the first error. You can use `:make!` to avoid jumping to the first error, what will prevent opening the buffer called "Build Stared...".

You could also try to tweak the `errorformat` which is set by `:compiler` command in order to make Vim parse the quickfix contents correctly, what would also enable you to use `:cn` and `:cp` to navigate on it. You can use the mscv compiler as a starting point - it can be found on $VIMRUNTIME/compiler folder. You probably can base on cs.vim (on the same folder), which has `errorformat` set for MS Visual Studio C#.